# App sometimes crashes at turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:didFindMatch: delegate method

Tags: ios

I have made a game using Game Center. Everything works great except for one thing. Around 1 out of 50 times, when creating a new match, either it is random opponent or by inviting a friend, my app might crash with this error being printed to my console:*fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*. Xcode also redirects me to the "location" of the crash, which is the turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:didFindMatch: delegate method. You can see at which line of code the crash happens down below.

Why it most of the time works, and some rare times crashes, I have no idea.

It is really hard to fix this bug, because I can spend 5 hours straight trying to make the crash happen, without success. I, myself, haven´t had this crash in a very long time, but the apple review team had this crash when reviewing my app.

This is my code:

```
func turnBasedMatchmakerViewController(viewController: GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController, didFindMatch match: GKTurnBasedMatch) {
    currentMatch = match
    presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,
        completion: nil)
    let firstParticipant = match.participants![0] as GKTurnBasedParticipant //This is where my app crashes!
    if firstParticipant?.lastTurnDate == nil {
        delegate!.enterNewGame(match)
    } else {
            if match.currentParticipant?.player!.playerID == GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().playerID {
                delegate!.takeTurn(match)
            } else {
                delegate!.layoutMatch(match)
            }
        }
    }
```

Fixing this is the only thing standing in my way to have my very first app in the App Store, so all kind of help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The error message indicates that that `match.participants![0]` can be `nil`. Use the `if let` syntax to fix this crash (as with all `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error messages). Basically, force-unwrapping optionals is a bad, bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change `delegate!.` to `delegate?.` everywhere.